# how to change switch imput text color in xml?

Tags: android, xml, switch-statement, textcolor

My text in my `switch` defined in a xml file won't to change it's color stay black as the activity background. I tried with the textcolor option without any success. Any ideas?

[image]

My xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hôte : "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <EditText 
            android:background="#40FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/hostname"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Utiliser Https : "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Switch 
            android:id="@+id/Switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="on"
            android:textOff="off"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is the screen jusst all black?

Comment: yes i don't like the white background

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a `switch`, add this to your `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="x" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#33CCFF</item>
</style>
```

Two options:

1. add this to your layout `XML` file:

   ```
   android:switchTextAppearance="@style/x"
   ```
2. add this to your Activity class after you've created an instance of your `switch`:

   ```
   switchInstance.setSwitchTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.x);
   ```

<sub>**Note:** path to `styles.xml` file: `Project Folder > res > values > styles.xml`</sub>

Comment: last question what's "@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" ?

Comment: @Wildchild7 that would change the font size from `medium` to `small`. You can probably get rid of that `parent=...` line or just make it medium. If you have a different `theme`, you probably have to modify that line to incorporate your `theme`.

However you end up making that line work for you, edit my answer or post it as a comment here so other people that view this can do it too.

Answer (score -1):

When you create an `instance` of your `EditText` or `TextView` in your `Activity` code, you can set the `TextColor`, or `Background Color` for that matter, there.

Ex.

```java
import android.graphics.Color; // add to top of your class

TextView x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y);

x.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("red")); // one way
x.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); // another way

x.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("colorString"));
x.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red int value, green int value, blue int value));
```